# Missing parameter "q" in bing image search API

Tags: bing, bing-api

When I tried to use similar products search from Bing search api with the following url with a valid api key in the header, it returns an error saying the request is missing a parameter "q". I need to search the image without a query string but just the image URL.

[https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?modulesRequested=SimilarProducts&mkt=en-us&form=BCSPRD&imgUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fzappos%2Flanding%2Fpages%2Fmensclothing%2FMelodyTest1%2FMensShoes1.*V506596164*.jpg&count=1](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?modulesRequested=SimilarProducts&mkt=en-us&form=BCSPRD&imgUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fm.media-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fzappos%2Flanding%2Fpages%2Fmensclothing%2FMelodyTest1%2FMensShoes1._V506596164_.jpg&count=1)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint is different. "Search" endpoint is meant for searching for images, given a query. "Details" endpoint will do the trick here. You need to do something like this:

```
GET https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/details?imgurl=YOUR_IMAGE_URL&modules=SimilarImages
```

Use this with your access key as a header and it will work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I had some trouble upgrading the endpoint url from v5 to v7 where it uses modules instead of modulesRequired.